# Downlaod doc/docx Javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to download a docx file via the URL that I receive from the backend. Based on the research, below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
async getUrlFromServer() => {
    return http:get('api/endpoint/', { responseType: 'blob' })
}
```

---

```
// get donwload url from the backend.
const downloadUrl = await this.getUrlFromServer()

const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(downloadUrl)
const link = document.createElement('a')
link.href = downloadUrl 

document.body.appendChild(link)
link.click()
```

The above code downloads the file in a zip format but the content inside the archive isn't the doc file.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Docx files are zip files

Comment: correct. But I am looking to download docx as it is not in zip so I can open it in MS Word or similar software.

Comment: Have you tried giving the zip file a `.docx` file extension and opening it in Word?

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
const data = await this.getUrlFromServer()

const blob = new Blob([data], { type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
' });
const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = downloadURL;
link.download = 'data.docx';
link.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code snippet is very close. Now I can download the file in Docx format. Although, when I open the file, the content inside the file is the downloaded URL not the file data. The reason for that is API returns the URL, not the file data itself.

Comment: Ok in then pass set the response from the server as the link.href and try again. If that doesn't work, make an http request to the url that comes from the server.